# Browser blocks popup

Tags: facebook, twitter, popup

I have a page where there is a textbox for status to type. When I click on the button "Update" I need that status to be updated in "Facebook" and "Twitter" in sequencial order. Also we need to check if the user is logged in with "Facebook" and "Twitter" or not

Currently what I am facing problem is my browser allows "Facebook" popup for authentication and post the status. But when the time comes for the twitter authentication, it is being blocked by browser. Is there any way to show both of the popup appear sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

IF the browswer is allowing for facebook popup to appear and not twitter there are two possible issues,

1. That the issue already existed for facebook at one point and you clicked always allow from facebook in regards to popups.
2. How the "popup" is generated, as you have no code I cannot guess as to what you have done to generate such a "popup" but my guess is no, if you are literally opening a new window or "popup" and the clients browser settings are to deny that action, your pretty much out of luck.

Again I cannot further diagnose you problem without any code